# How to replace extension of a .pdf file with .doc in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a pdf file . I want to remove the extension of it from .pdf to .doc to print & save that file data into a word document file

Comment: Kindly read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question so other can help.

Answer (score -1):

By using the package [pdf-officegen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-officegen), the following code will convert the PDF file to a Word document.

```
import {Powerpoint, Word} from 'pdf-officegen'
const w = new Word([options])
   
w.convertFromPdf('input.pdf', [options,] (err, result) => {
 //Do something with the result (filepath to output) 
})
```